# Ember Way to Add Rss Feed without third party widget, Front-end only

Tags: ember.js, rss

I am using Ember 3.0 at the moment. Wrote my first lines of code in ANY language about 1 year ago (I switched careers from something totally unrelated to development), but I quickly took to ember. So, not a ton of experience, but not none. I am writing a multi-tenant site which will include about 20 different sites, all with one Ember frontend and a RubyOnRails backend. I am about 75% done with the front end, now just loading content into it. I haven’t started on the backend yet, one, because I don’t have MUCH experience with backend stuff, and two, because I haven’t needed it yet. My sites will be informational to begin with and I’ll build it up from there.

So. I am trying to implement a news feed on my site. I need it to pull in multiple rss feeds, perhaps dozens, filtered by keyword, and display them on my site. I’ve been scouring the web for days just trying to figure out where to get started. I was thinking of writing a service that parses the incoming xml, I tried using a third party widget (which I DON’T really want to do. Everything on my site so far has been built from scratch and I’d like to keep it that way), but in using these third party systems I get some random cross domain errors and node-child errors which only SOMETIMES pop up. Anyway, I’d like to write this myself, if possible, since I’m trying to learn (and my brain is wired to do the code myself - the only way it sticks with me).

Ultimately, every google result I read says RSS feeds are easy to implement. I don’t know where I’m going wrong, but I’m simply looking for:

1: An “Ember-way” starting point. 2: Is this possible without a backend? 3: Do I have to use a third party widget/aggregator? 4: Whatever else you think might help on the subject.

Any help would be appreciated. Here in New Hampshire, there are basically no resources, no meetings, nothing. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the results I get back when searching on this topic, it looks like you’ll get a few snags if you try to do this in the browser:

1. CORS header issues (sounds like you’ve already hit this)
2. The joy of working with XML in JavaScript (that just **might** be sarcasm , it’s actually unlikely to be fun)

If your goal is to do this as a learning exercise, then doing it Javascript/Ember will definitely help you learn lots of new things. You might start with this article as a jumping off point: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/12/08/parsing-rss-feeds-in-javascript-options/

However, if you want to have this be maintainable for the long run and want things to go quickly and smoothly, I would highly recommend moving the RSS parsing system into your backend and feeding simple data out to Ember. There are enough gotchas and complexities to RSS feeds over time that using a battle-tested library is going to be your best way to stay sane. And loading that type of library up in Ember (while quite doable) will end up increasing your application size. You will avoid all those snags (and more I’m probably not thinking of) if you move your parsing back to the server ...

Comment: Ok.  Took your advice.  My backend is up and running (rails api) and I am parsing feeds from my database using feedjira.  CORS is figured out, and Ember is pulling in and displaying the feeds, so I'm making progress.  Any thoughts on how I would aggregate only articles that include a keyword or topic, again using feedjira and rails?  I cannot seem to find much on the subject.